# nginx not stripping www using rewrite

Tags: nginx

I want to strip the www from my url in my nginx configuration and looking around the documentation and stack overflow posts I wrote the following configuration but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
server_name {
          server_name www.subdomain.domain.com;
          rewrite ^(.*) https://subdomain.domain.com/$1 permanent
        }
server_name {
            server_name subdomain.domain.com;

            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

            root /file;
            index index.html index.htm app.js;

            location /{

                   proxy_pass https://subdomain.domain.com:443/;
                   proxy_redirect off;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            }
            location /*/ {
                   proxy_pass https://subdomain.domain.com:443/;
                   proxy_redirect off;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            }

        # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
        #location /RequestDenied {
        #       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        #}

        error_page 404 /404.html;


}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working at all. However whenever I try to go to the site using www.subdomain.domain.com i can't access the site but doing https://subdomain.domain.com works fine. Any advice on this would be great thanks.

Comment: You have many syntax errors. Have you restarted nginx?

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in nginx config (server_name instead server), and try return instead rewrite as more proper way:

```
server {
    server_name www.subdomain.domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://subdomain.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```